# Apache2 on Ubuntu 16.04: Default configuration for FileETag

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, configuration

I have a question regarding the ETag configuration with Apache 2.4. The Apache documentation (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#fileetag) states that the default value for FileETag is `INode MTime Size`. However, I am not able to confirm this behavior with my setup.

I am running a Ubuntu 16.04 server with Apache 2.4 from the default repositories. My plan was to prevent Apache from using the inode to generate ETags, because of CVE-2003-1418.

However, I noticed that a `FileETag -INode` did not change the generated ETag (example: c83-54a250499ffc0). So I tried with `FileETag +INode` and a new block appeared (ac2981-c83-54a250499ffc0). With `FileETag INode` only the Inode was returned (ac2981).

I tried the same with the official httpd Docker image (https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/) and noticed the same behavior.

First I assumed that Ubuntu modifies its Apache package, but the Docker image compiles from source and has the same behavior.

So, what is going on here? Is the default value in the Apache documentation wrong? I just want to be sure if I need extra configuration or if I can trust on the default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're exactly right - inode was [removed from the defaults](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1199086) for the [same security reason](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49623) you're citing, though the documentation was apparently never updated.